# Custom control default style

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, styles

I like to separate some of my custom controls to a dll.

lets assume I have the following example control:

MyControl.cs

```
namespace MyControlsNs {
    public class MyControl : ContentControl {
        public static DependencyProperty IsGreatProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsGreat",
                                    typeof (bool),
                                    typeof (MyControl),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(true));
        public bool IsGreat { 
            get { return (bool) GetValue(IsGreatProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsGreatProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

MyControl.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyControlsNs"> 
    <Style x:Key="MyControl" TargetType="controls:MyControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsGreat}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

If I'd like to use MyControl I actually do the following:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyMainViewClass"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyControlsNs">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MyControl.xaml" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <controls:MyControl IsGreat="true" Style="{StaticResource MyControl}" />
</UserControl>
```

My goal is keeping the the definition of RD and Style, when I use it in MyMainViewClass; like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyMainViewClass"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyControlsLib.MyControlsNs;assembly=MyControlsLib">
    <controls:MyControl IsGreat="true" />
</UserControl>
```

How can I define my default Style for MyControl?
I found this thread [Creating default style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237611/creating-default-style-for-custom-control), but integrating didn't work for me:

```
static MyControl() {
   DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl))); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A default Style for a custom control in a library is located in a file named `Generic.xaml` in a folder named `Themes` in your library project.

Note also that a default Style resource does not have the `x:Key` attribute set.

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyControlsNs"> 
    <Style TargetType="controls:MyControl">
        ...
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Overriding the default value of the `DefaultStyleKey` dependency property of the custom control makes sure that the default Style is actually applied to the correct control type:

```
static MyControl()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
        typeof(MyControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl))); 
}
```

Finally, you would also have to set the [`ThemeInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.themeinfoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute in your library's `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(ResourceDictionaryLocation.None,
                     ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)]
```

Please see the [Control Authoring Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN for further reading.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you. My mistake was defining my RD at the file named MyControl.xaml except Themes/Generic.xaml. Now everything is fine.